# remove virtual host on mac

Tags: apache, mamp, host

I'm using MAMP PRO on my Mac (running OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion).
Today I added a new host and managed to name it sitename **.org** which now making me unable to access it online.

Fist I tried to rename the host - didn't work.
Then I tried to remove the host - didn't work.
Tried to rename the folder (wich also was named *sitename.org*) - didn't work.

So basically now I cannot access this particular site at all.
I've set the correct disk location and everything, but it just uses "Document-Root: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs". Even now, after I've removed the host, it still says" "erver name: sitename.org".

Also restated the machine...

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe MAMP Pro sets all the apache settings on launch, saving them in its preferences plist or some such, so:

- Start MAMP Pro
- click to the sites tab
- click the + button below
- fill in the details for your site (desired local url eg sitename or sitename.dev)
- restart MAMP

There is a video for Mamp Pro here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hMW8sTFftI

if you have any cruft from trying to set this up manually, check in your `/etc/hosts` file, remove any lines that relate to your 'sitename.org'.  This way, your machine will look online for sitename.org rather than thinking that the site should be served locally.

You may need to flush your dns cache? for 10.8 try:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Comment: Hey, and thanks your your reply. although this happened some time ago, I really appreciate your suggestion. After a lot of fumbeling, I just formatted and reinstalled the OS. But I keep this in mind if I run into the same thing again...

Comment: my pleasure  :) i don't use Pro any more - prefer to get familiar with the apache files (its pretty much fill in the gaps / copy paste for MAMP)

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you meant? I use MAMP Pro because it allows me to have multiple testing environment without the need for `localhost/sitename1/`, `localhost/sitename2/` etc. This also lets me have an 100% identical testing-environment (links and folderpaths) as the site online.